# Create Python class where the attributes is defined dynamically

Tags: python, metaprogramming

Sorry if this has been asked before. Is it possible to create class in Python dynamically where attributes is not defined in the `__init__` method of the class.

For example with this class

```
class Person(object):
  def __init__(self):
    ...
```

I can dynamically put in the attributes during initialization like this:

`person = Person(name='Joe')`

and access it like this:

```
person.name
>>> Joe
```

Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to assign the keyword argument dict to the `__dict__` attribute of the class:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        self.__dict__ = kw
person = Person(name='Joe')
print person.name
```

prints

```
Joe
```

To add attributes after object creation, use

```
def add_attributes(self, **kw):
    self.__dict__.update(kw)
```

You could also use `.update()` in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using [descriptors](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) ([detailed explanation](http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm)). This also enables you to add attributes after the object has been created.